# Wordpress modify footer

Tags: wordpress, footer

**Following example Code given in footer.php:**

```
<footer id="test" role="role">

    <div id="test-generator" class="clearfix">
        <?php do_action( 'test_open' ); ?>

        <div class="copyright">
            blabla
        </div>

        <div class="powered">
            blabla
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'test_close' ); ?>
    </div>

</footer>
</div>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

the footer.php is part of a wordpress theme. I would like to add some line after "blabla" in div.class copyright. This should be done without modifying the footer.php. Is ther any way to do so?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: you could do that with functions.php ?? or no files on the theme should be modified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a function that is hooked to the "test_close" action and include it in your `functions.php` or [Custom Functions Plugin](http://justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-custom-functions-php/):

```
add_action( 'test_close', 'my_function' );
function my_function(){
    echo "<br/>This is on the next line";
}
```

Comment: First thanks for your answer! I allready implemented a 'custom functions plugin'. When I use your lines of code it adds a new line **under** the div powered. Is there a way to change something inbetween the **copyright.div**? What I could do is start a comment in the **'test_open'** hook and end the comment in **'test close'**  - just rewrite the whole thing. But this wouldn't be very clean as the comment still reminds and would bloat the code..

Comment: While not that elegant, you are on the right track - if you want to use the hooks instead of modifying the `footer.php`, you would need to do exactly what you said and either comment it out or include it in a `<div style='display:none;'></div>`. Another option would be to create a child theme that just overrides `footer.php` so that it isn't overwritten if you update the parent theme. You would copy the whole file and leave out anything you didn't want in the `footer.php` of the child theme. http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Thank you for the help! Both options (hooks & child-theme) solve the problem, so I go with the cleaner one (child-theme). :)